Azure DevOps Plugin to list latest runs of certain pipelines?
We are using Azure DevOps to keep and process our codebase with a multitude of pipelines.
The built-in list of pipelines currently allows for accessing pipelines in one out of three ways:

Recent: Lists all, or many, pipelines ordered by which one was run most recently.
All: Shows all registered pipelines in their folder hierarchy.
Runs: Shows the latest runs across all pipelines.

Neither of these is really useful for our work1. What we actually need is a summary of

a subset of the pipelines (just a couple of specific build pipelines, there's absolutely no need to have all the validation and tooling pipelines in there that may be running for one reason or another)
with information on their latest run (in particular, the run label, the outcome, the tags - configurable columns would be nice to have)
only for certain resources (as we only want to see build pipeline runs from the release branches, not all the runs of the same pipeline from feature branches in the same repo)
split up by resource (as, if we currently maintain four releases, we want to see four entries for the same pipeline, with the latest run of each release)

None of the above needs to be determined automatically - we're totally fine with manually listing.

the pipeline names
the resource branch names
preferrably some custom grouping headers and/or some custom human-readable title for each line

in a JSON config or similar file.
Optional requirements:

We can somehow configure multiple such "profiles" that visitors of the summary can switch between (think "Public Product Releases", "Internal Tools", ...).
The tool displays the last pipeline run and the last successful pipeline run, whenever that may have been. (Note that we do not want to see anything beyond that, i.e. seeing N last pipeline runs (for any N > 1) is explicitly not desired.)

Is there a free-to-use Azure DevOps plugin that fulfills this purpose?
As a fallback, even a standalone tool might be acceptable.

1: What I mean by this is: Non-technical colleagues such as our product managers and project management need to know about the status of certain pipelines - the ones that create the final setup packages, for instance, for various versions that customers are waiting for. Likewise, they are interested in a few deployment pipelines of sample systems. On many occasions, the same even applies to some developers who just want to see the final product status.
These users are not interested in seeing all the pipelines, including all the PR validation and other tooling pipelines that keep running all the time. They are not interested in searching for the right pipeline among the entire list, nor in searching for the relevant run for each codebase branch that goes into a release.
